# Python checking users input

Tags: python, input

So, basically, this is my code:

```
import random
import os

answer = input('What is the problem with your mobile phone? Please do not enter more than one sentence.')
print('The program has detected that you have entered a query regarding: ' 
if 'wet' or 'water' or 'liquid' or 'mobile' in answer:
    print('Put your mobile phone inside of a fridge, it sounds stupid but it should work!')
```

What I want to know is, say for example if the user enters the keywords 'wet' and 'mobile' as their input, how do I feed back to them knowing that my program has recognised their query.

So by saying something like 'The program has detected that you have entered a query regarding:' how do I filter their keywords into this sentence, say, if they entered 'My mobile phone has gotten wet recently', I want to pick out 'mobile' and 'wet' without saying:

```
print('The program has detected that you have entered wet')
```

Because that sounds stupid IMO.

Thanks

Comment: Put the print statement inside your `if` test. Actually, your entire `if` statement is invalid an needs to be re-coded.

Comment: Yeah, and I knew it should have been an if not an elif and I need to remove import os as well, I was just trying something out before hence why there is un needed bits of code

Comment: But I want a way to pull specific strings from the users input, for example say if there was a 'valid inputs' list and a couple of the strings from the users input matched the list, then it would print said strings

Comment: How do you suggest I code it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a tuple, a list and `any` function:

```
SEND_REPORT_TUPLE = ('wet', 'water', 'liquid', 'mobile')
#make a list from the input
input_list = answer.split(" ")
#And then the use any function with comprehension list
if any(e in SEND_REPORT_TUPLE for e in input_list):
    print("The program has detected a query...")
```

Comment: One question, what is a tuple?

Comment: @Thom9son 
*A tuple is a sequence of immutable Python objects. Tuples are sequences, just like lists. The differences between tuples and lists are, the tuples cannot be changed unlike lists and tuples use parentheses, whereas lists use square brackets.*


>> In the example, you can use a tuple or a list.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should solve your problem. Just put the print statement inside the if condition! Very simple, I guess :)

```
import random
import os

answer = input('What is the problem with your mobile phone? Please do not enter more than one sentence.')
if 'wet' or 'water' or 'liquid' or 'mobile' in answer:
    print('The program has detected that you have entered a query regarding: water') # or anything else wet or whatever
    print('Put your mobile phone inside of a fridge, it sounds stupid but it should work!')
```

Comment: Thats the thing though, I knew how to do and and that's pretty easy, but instead of saying a query regarding 'water' I was wondering if there is any way to use a list or something to pick out strings from the users sentence and cross reference them, and if there is any matches, it uses them from the list and prints them. However, if there is no matches I am going to have it so they can choose whether or not to write a report to a technician with a report number etc, and this will just write some information to a file

Comment: Yes, that very well would work and I know that just from looking at it, because I considered just doing that but it seems pretty basic in my opinion

Comment: So what is your expected output?

`The program has detected that you have entered a query regarding: mobile wet` ?

Comment: Check @Angel Cruijff's answer that I edited. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Angel Cruijff: I changed your answer so that I could access which `e` matched a word in the input_list.